# How to request.getParameterNames into List of strings?

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to get `request.getParameterNames()` as a list of Strings? I need to have it in this form.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just [construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) a new `ArrayList` wrapping the keyset of the [request parameter map](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29).

```
List<String> parameterNames = new ArrayList<String>(request.getParameterMap().keySet());
// ...
```

I only wonder how it's useful to have it as `List<String>`. A `Set<String>` would make much more sense as parameter names are supposed to be **unique** (a `List` can contain duplicate elements). A `Set<String>` is also exactly what the map's keyset already represents.

```
Set<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterMap().keySet();
// ...
```

Or perhaps you don't need it at all for the particular functional requirement for which you [thought](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that massaging the parameter names into a `List<String>` would be the solution. Perhaps you *actually* intented to iterate over it in an enhanced loop, for example? That's also perfectly possible on a `Map`.

```
for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue()[0];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution worked for me, however, as I am relatively new to Java, I was not sure what is the type of `Entry` and the one that worked for me was `java.util.Map.Entry`. However, I had to change the declaration as `Entry<String, String[]> entry : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()` and the value will be an array with one element  `writer.println("Param Value: " + value[0].toString());`. I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to getParameterNames from servlets by using `HttpServletRequest.getParameterNames()` method. This returns an `enumeration`. We can cast the enemeration elements into `string` and add those  into an `ArrayList` of parameters as follows.

```
 ArrayList<String> parameterNames = new ArrayList<String>();
 Enumeration enumeration = request.getParameterNames();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        String parameterName = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
        parameterNames.add(parameterName);
    }

 // you can do whatever you want to do with parameter lists..
```

Answer (score 7):

You can probably use this:

`List<String> parameterNamesList =   Collections.list(request.getParameterNames());`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to convert the `Enumeration` to an `Iterator`, and then the `Iterator` to a `List`:

```
Lists.<String> newArrayList(Iterators.forEnumeration(request.getParameterNames()))
```