# How to check which one variable is not null among multiple variables in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, null, nullable

I am developing an Online Shopping Website. I have many(3-4 as of now) items in one particular section; eg. I have 3 items in my **Winter Wear** section. And I have one common *buy-now* page for all those items.

*winter-wear.jsp*

```
<input type="hidden" name="black-jacket" value="999"/>
```

To get to know, ***from which page the request has come*** or in terms of my project ***of which item's buy-now button has clicked***, I used this particular line of code. *value* contains the price of the particular item, I know it's a bad idea to store the price like what I did.

*buy-now.jsp*

```
<% 
        String blackjacket = request.getParameter("black-jacket");
        String graysweatshirt = request.getParameter("gray-sweatshirt");
        String bluehudi = request.getParameter("blue-hudi");
%>
```

Now, each of these variables contains the price of the particular item. But after clicking on the buy-now button of any particular item, the price of that particular item will be stored in the variable and other variables will contain the *null*.

I have unknown numbers of these variables. Out of these, only one variable contains the price and all other variables contain the null.

Output:

[image]

How can I get to know which variable is not-null(As I have an unknown number of variables, I can't use the if statement to check for not-null) and get the value of a non-nullable variable only; i.e. price of the particular item? I meant is there any function like *anyonenotnull* or do we need to write our own method for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this overall, but to quickly answer your problem, you could use `request.getParameterMap()` and then loop through each of the result.

[How to request.getParameterNames into List of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281446/how-to-request-getparameternames-into-list-of-strings)

Experiment with the below and change it around a bit and you should have something that works

```
String boughtItem;

for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() != null) {
        boughtItem = entry.getKey();
        break;
    }
}
```